# Multiplying two columns of same dataframe thats dependent on same column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have the below dataframe,

|  | customer name | sales rep | sku | category | Number | date | commission |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Mueller and Sons | Loring Predovic | GP-14407 | quantity | 19 | 2016-02-13 05:58:34 | 0.040 |
| 1 | Mueller and Sons | Loring Predovic | GP-14407 | unit price | 300 | 2016-02-13 05:58:34 | 0.025 |
| 2 | Purdy and Sons | Teagan O’Keefe | NZ-99565 | quantity | 32 | 2016-01-23 02:15:50 | 0.025 |
| 3 | Purdy and Sons | Teagan O’Keefe | NZ-99565 | unit price | 1000 | 2016-01-23 02:15:50 | 0.025 |
| 4 | Mueller and Sons | Loring Predovic | GP-14407 | first price | 200 | 2016-02-13 05:58:34 | 0.040 |
| 5 | Purdy and Sons | Teagan O’Keefe | NZ-99565 | first price | 800 | 2016-01-23 02:15:50 | 0.025 |

I need to calculate the total price for each customer like

For example, for Customer "Mueller and Sons" I need to calculate total price like "category(quantity's Number) * category(unit price's Number)" ie, (19*300).

so I tried to do groupby of customer name and multiplying the data from same column by not successful.

```
df.groupby(['customer name']).(category='quantity'['Number']*category='unit price'['Number'])
```

can some one help me with this?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Do you just need the sum of the unit price * quantity for each customer?

Comment: You would really want to change your dataframe, by replacing "category" with a few columns like "quanity", "unit price" and "first price", and their cells containing the respective values (which then also removes the "Number" column). That will solve your problem and future problems much better.

Comment: @mathew, I need to find product of unit price * quantity for each customer. But the problem is both values are available in same column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to find only product of unit and price:

```py
q = df[df["category"].eq("quantity")].groupby("customer name")["Number"].first()
u = (
    df[df["category"].eq("unit price")]
    .groupby("customer name")["Number"]
    .first()
)
print(q * u)
```

Prints:

```
customer name
Mueller and Sons     5700
Purdy and Sons      32000
Name: Number, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pivot your dataframe and multiply the columns:

```
df_pivot = (df.pivot(index=['customer name', 'sku'],
                     columns='category',
                     values='Number')
              .fillna(0)
              .reset_index()
           )
df_pivot['total'] = df_pivot['quantity']*df_pivot['unit price']
```

output:

```
category     customer name       sku  first price  quantity  unit price  total
0         Mueller and Sons  GP-14407          200        19         300   5700
1           Purdy and Sons  NZ-99565          800        32        1000  32000
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it can be solved with `pivot`.

```
df.pivot(index = ['customer name','sku'],columns = 'category',values='Number')[['quantity','unit price']].prod(1)
```